# Handlebars: Best Way to Show Spinner While Waiting for AJAX request

Tags: ajax, handlebars.js

I know the answer to "Best Way to Show Spinner While Waiting for AJAX request?" but what would be best approach when we semantic templates e.g. handlebars are used.

I've a theoretical solution to share but would like to know if there is any better approach.

Here is the template I defined:

```
<script id="AnalyticsTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="circle-tile-content dark-blue">
        <div class="circle-tile-description text-faded">Free Subscriptions</div>
        {{#if FreeSubscriptionsCount}}
        <div class="circle-tile-number text-faded ">{{FreeSubscriptionsCount}}</div>
        {{else}}
        <div class="preloading"></div>
        {{/if}}
        @*<a class="circle-tile-footer" href="#">More Info <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a>*@
    </div>
</script>
```

Current approach is to use `if` condition, and compile the same template twice. First, before the AJAX call with empty data and later on AJAX success/error.

Hope this is understood, if not, feel free to ask.

Any suggestion or feedback would be highly appreciated.

Comment: are you using ember? if not why is this tagged with ember, if yes, use a loading substate. But what ember version is it then?

Comment: As mentioned; if you're using Ember.j, use a [loading substate](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/).

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I'm not using emberjs but I was expecting a better solution there, so I tagged this (also the tag was in suggestion too).